# Is object file generated during single step compilation?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

According to [How does the compilation/linking process work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work)

> During compilation, the compiler takes the pre-processor's output and 
>   produces an object file from it.

Additionally,

> Compilation refers to the processing of source code files (.c, .cc,
>   or .cpp) and the creation of an 'object' file.

So for example:

If I have 2 files `test1.cpp` and `test2.cpp`. I can do modular compilation with `g++ -c test1.cpp test2.cpp` which generates 2 object files `test1.o` and `test.o`.

But what about during single step compilation? Where I have 1 file `test1.cpp`. With the command `g++ test1.cpp`, no object file appears to be generated in the directory. So what happens during single step compilation?

Comment: The C++ Standard has nothing to say about how compilation and/or linking must work. This is down to the compiler and linker implementation.

Comment: "With the command g++ test.cpp, no object file appears to be generated" - Then you need to look harder. Unless the compilation failed, that should most definitely produce an object file.

Comment: @NeilButterworth moot point. OP didn't ask about C++ standard quote on that.

Comment: @JesperJuhl with given command, it won't.

Comment: @Sergey It is tagged as C++ and contains `(C++)` in the headline.

Comment: @NeilButterworth so what? There are numerous C++ questions which are of application domain nature. Are you going to say that C++ Standard says nothing abouy, say, SFML (very popular topic in the tag)? I also disagree with your duplicate, OP is asking specific, g++ question. I would like to reopen the question.

Comment: Yes, I am and often do.

Comment: " I would like to reopen the question" - is anyone stopping you?

Comment: @NeilButterworth I think this would be very narrow reading. Questions for standards are tagged with Language Lawyer, and I see no issue with application domain questions in C++ tag. Well, the last thing I want is to get in tug of war here. You certainly had you reasons to close it, and I would like to see if you would reconsider and agree that the question might deserve an answer on it's own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with g++ command line. If you just run it with

```
g++ file.cpp
```

It will compile the code to intermediate object file, and than invoke linker and create `a.out` executable file, removing the intermediate object file after this.

Comment: oh I see.. appreciated